# Can't delete a symlink from /usr/lib

Tags: fedora, symlink

I'm on Fedora 27. I want to delete a symlink from `/usr/lib`, but can't because of `Operation not permitted`. I'm under root and here are commands and the output:

```
[root@thinkpad lib]# ls -al cpp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 15 15:01 cpp -> ../bin/cpp
...
[root@thinkpad lib]# lsattr ../bin/cpp
--------------e---- ../bin/cpp
...
[root@thinkpad lib]# rm -f cpp
rm: cannot remove 'cpp': Operation not permitted
```

SELinux is disabled. Why can't I delete this symlink?

The reason why I want to delete this symlink is because I can't update packages because of this. When I run `dnf update`, I get the following error:

```
  Upgrading        : cpp-7.3.1-5.fc27.x86_64                                                                                               29/77 
Error unpacking rpm package cpp-7.3.1-5.fc27.x86_64
Error unpacking rpm package cpp-7.3.1-5.fc27.x86_64
error: unixODBC-2.3.5-2.fc27.i686: install failed
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/lib/cpp;5aa2d6ee: cpio: symlink
```

Comment: I don't suppose you have /usr mounted read-only?

Comment: How can I check this one? Running `ls -l` give this: `drwxr-xr-x.  13 root root  4096 Jan  4 23:25 usr`

Comment: `df /usr` would show if it is a separate partition; `mount | grep " on / "` or `mount | grep " on /usr "` or `sudo blockdev --getro /dev/foo` on the corresponding device would show if it's readonly (`ro` instead of `rw` in the options)

Comment: Looks like it is read-write:
`/dev/mapper/fedora_thinkpad-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)`

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. That question was also opened by me. But I've resolved the SELinux issue. And the issue from this question is another one.

Comment: Seems to me you're still trying to remove the cpp link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74272/discussion-between-vitalii-plagov-and-jeff-schaller).

Comment: Try `strace` on `rm` it may give you more details. Also I kind of remember having the same problem in an LXC container and this was due of not enough unix capabilities given to the (unprivileged) container. Are you in something like that?

Comment: Run with `strace` and got the following output: https://justpaste.it/1i4xp
But what should I look at this output? How can I identify the problem out of this output response?